# i18n with messages file on configmap k8s

Tags: java, kubernetes, internationalization, microservices

i'm trying to mount my messages files for various languages on a configMap on kubernetes but for some reason i can't reach the variables inside the configmap.
This is basename in cluster-prop: spring.messages.basename=config/i18n/messages.

This is my file.yml:

```yaml
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: tenant-config 
          volumeMounts:
            - name: i18n-conf
              mountPath: /config/i18n/messages.properties
              subPath: messages.properties
            - name: i18n-conf
              mountPath: /config/i18n/messages_it.properties
              subPath: messages_it.properties
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            items:
              - key: messages.properties
                path: messages.properties
              - key: messages_it.properties
                path: messages_it.properties
            name: tag-management-i18n-cm
          name: i18n-conf
```

and this is my configmap:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  messages.properties: |
    error.requestid= Missing request header 'requestId'
    invalid.tenantid= 'X-TenantId'
  messages_it.properties: |
    error.requestid= Intestazione della richiesta \"requestId\" mancante
    invalid.tenantid = \"X-TenantId\" non valido
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorry, thi is my yml:
     envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: tenant-config 
          volumeMounts:
            - name: i18n-conf
              mountPath: /config/i18n/messages.properties
              subPath: messages.properties
            - name: i18n-conf
              mountPath: /config/i18n/messages_it.properties
              subPath: messages_it.properties
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            items:
              - key: messages.properties
                path: messages.properties
              - key: messages_it.properties
                path: messages_it.properties
            name: tag-management-i18n-cm
          name: i18n-conf
```

Comment: Hello. Can you edit your question, if your want to replace your YAML ? Please do not create an answer for that.